# Get fill rates in another table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a script to calculate the fill rates for each column in a table `Data_table` and insert it into a second table `Metadata_table`.

The `Data_table` has 30 columns in it, and some columns have 100% data in them, and some have less than 100% (due to nulls).

My code to calculate the fill rate looks like this,

```
 select 
     cast(sum(case 
                 when employee_id is null 
                    then 0 
                    else 1 
              end) / cast(count(1) as float ) * 100 as decimal(8,3)) as employee_id_fill,
     .....--/*so on for 30 columns..*/ 
from 
    [Data_table]
```

The `Metadata_table` should look like this:

```
Table_name  |  Colmn_name  |  Fill_rate
[Data_table]|   Colomn_a   | 100%
[Data_table]|   Colomn_b   | 89%
[Data_table]|   Colomn_c   | 100%
 and so on...
```

I think

```
unpivot
```

can work here, but i am unable to get the column names into the [Metadata_table] automatically.

I tried using this for automating the column names-

```
COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('DBO.[DATA_TABLE]'),'COLOMN_A')
```

but this has not worked so far.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You would need a dynamic pivot, to do this for all columns in the table, where you don't know the names of the columns in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.columns` for grabbing the column names. You can join it to `sys.tables` by the `object_id` if you ever need to associate the two.

For example:

```
SELECT c.NAME
FROM SYS.TABLES t
     INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE t.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('DBO.[Data_Table]');
```

You can generate SQL from here in the format you wanted by creating an expression to query your table and then unpivot it.

Another approach could be a while loop to do inserts into your metadata table. If you're working with a very large table this option will be more expensive so keep it in mind. I used an example table `dbo.Attendance_Records` and this script will print out the example SQL, *not execute it.* You would want to change it to call sp_executesql on that text.

```
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(128) = 'DBO.[Attendance_Records]'
       ,@MetaTable NVARCHAR(128) = 'DBO.[Metadata_Table]'
       ,@ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@Iterator INT = 1
       ,@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT c.NAME
      ,c.COLUMN_ID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) AS RN
INTO #Cols
FROM SYS.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@Table);

WHILE @Iterator <= (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RN),0) FROM #Cols)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = (SELECT NAME FROM #Cols WHERE RN = @Iterator)
        SET @SQL =  'INSERT INTO ' + @MetaTable + ' (Table_Name, Column_Name, Fill_Rate) '
                  + 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@Table,'DBO.','') + ''', ''' + @ColumnName + ''', 100 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3), SUM(CASE WHEN [' + @ColumnName + '] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) / COUNT(1) AS [' + @ColumnName + '_fill]' + ' FROM ' + @Table

        PRINT @SQL
        SET @Iterator += 1
    END
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, i was able to automate using this script to check after every load process in the ETL.

Comment: Glad to hear it suited your needs!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to have the column names you would need to so something along these lines.

```
select ColumnName = 'Colomn_a'
    , FillRate = count(distinct Colomn_a) / count(*) * 1.0 --must multiply by 1.0 to avoid integer math
from YourTable

UNION ALL

select 'Colomn_b'
    , count(distinct Colomn_b) / count(*) * 1.0
from YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I actually did look into this approach. But I have close to 400 columns in various tables, so i was hoping for a more automated way to do this.

Comment: You can leverage dynamic sql but I would be gravely concerned if you have tables with over 400 columns. That is a pretty clear indication that the design is in some need of normalization.

Comment: I would agree.. what i meant was, there were a total of 400 columns distributed over 15 tables. There are a average of 25 columns per table.

Comment: So you need to spend a couple hours to write queries for those 15 tables. That isn't a big deal at all.

Comment: Yes, its done. I will write a while loop to pick up table names from system objects and then this loop will pick up column names for each table name.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate method of Mike R's

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFillRate_new]    -- EXEC [GetFillRate] 'TestEmp'
(
    @TableName                  NVARCHAR(128),
    @Include_BlankAsNotFilled   BIT = 1 -- 0-OFF(Default); 1-ON(Blank As Not Filled Data)
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;   

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE [TYPE]='U' AND [NAME]=@TableName )     
    BEGIN
        SELECT Result = 1 , Reason ='Table not exists in this Database' ;
        RETURN 1;
    END;

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql=''
 select
   @sql=@sql+'select 
        '''+c.column_name+''' as [Column Name],
         cast((100*(sum(
                    case when ' + 
                        case
                            when @include_blankasnotfilled = 0 
                              then '[' + c.column_name + '] is not null'
                            when c.collation_name is null
                              then '[' + c.column_name + '] is not null'
                            else 'isnull([' + c.column_name + '],'''')<>'''' ' end + 
                    ' then 1 else 0 end)*1.0 / count(*))) 
                as decimal(5,2)) as [Fill Rate (%)]
from '+c.table_name+' 
     union all '
from
        information_schema.columns as c 
    inner join information_schema.tables as t 
    on c.table_name=t.table_name 
where
        t.table_type='base table' and
        t.table_name =@tablename
set @sql=left(@sql,len(@sql)-10)
--print @sql
exec(@sql)
end
```

You can find more details into this blog post https://exploresql.com/2019/12/14/how-to-find-fill-rate-in-a-table/

Answer (score 0):

**Challenges:**

The Schema changes like below things makes our Fill Rate approach little difficult than actual.

- Table name changes
- Column name changes
- Data type changes
- Removing Existing columns
- Adding New Columns

Due to the above challenges, we cannot simply go for Static Solution to find Fill Rate of a table. Instead, we need something like Dynamic Approach to avoid our future re-works.

**Prerequisite:**

In the below sample, we are going to use one stored procedure named ‘Get_FillRate’ for demo. If any one have the same object name in database, please make sure to change the below stored procedure name.

***Sample Table Creation with Data Loading Script***

```
--dropping temp table if exists
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#TestEmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TestEmp;
  
CREATE TABLE #TestEmp
(
    [TestEmp_Key] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Age] INT NULL,
    [Address] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [PhoneNo] VARCHAR(11) NULL,
    [Inserted_dte] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Updated_dte] DATETIME NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestEmp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 (
    TestEmp_Key ASC
 )
);
GO
   
INSERT INTO #TestEmp
(EmpName,Age,[Address],PhoneNo,Inserted_dte)
VALUES
('Arul',24,'xxxyyy','1234567890',GETDATE()),
('Gokul',22,'zzzyyy',NULL,GETDATE()),
('Krishna',24,'aaa','',GETDATE()),
('Adarsh',25,'bbb','1234567890',GETDATE()),
('Mani',21,'',NULL,GETDATE()),
('Alveena',20,'ddd',NULL,GETDATE()),
('Janani',30,'eee','',GETDATE()),
('Vino',26,NULL,'1234567890',GETDATE()),
('Madhi',25,'ggg',NULL,GETDATE()),
('Ronen',25,'ooo',NULL,GETDATE()),
('Visakh',25,'www',NULL,GETDATE()),
('Jayendran',NULL,NULL,NULL,GETDATE());
GO
   
SELECT [TestEmp_Key],[EmpName],[Age],[Address],[PhoneNo],[Inserted_dte],[Updated_dte] FROM #TestEmp;
GO
```

***Temp Table - #TestEmp***

[image]

SQL Procedure For Finding Fill Rate in a Table - Dynamic Approach
Input Parameters

Both of the Input Parameters are mandatory.

1. @p_TableName - Data type used for this input Parameter is NVARCHAR(128) and Nullability is NOT NULL.
2. @p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled - Data type used for this input Parameter is BIT and Nullability is NOT NULL and either 0 or 1 needs to give. 0 is by Default and 0 means OFF. 1 is ON (when given as 1 - Blank entries will be considered As Not Filled Data).

Output Columns

There are Two output Columns. both of those are Non Nullable Output Columns.

1. [Column Name] - Data type used for this Output Column is sysname and Nullability is NOT NULL. All the Column Names for the user given Table Name would come as row values.
2. [Fill Rate (%)] -  Data type used for this Output Column is DECIMAL(5,2) and Nullability is NOT NULL. Values from 0.00 to 100.00 would come in result with respective Column Names.

Info reg Stored Procedure

- Created the store Procedure named - 'Get_FillRate'.
- To avoid the number of rows returned, set NOCOUNT as ON.
- Try, Catch Blocks are added for error handling's.
- To read Uncommitted Modifications, set TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL as READ UNCOMMITTED.
- Parameter Sniffing Concept is also included.
- Some handling's done on the Table Name input parameters to support user typing table name formats like '.table_name','..table_name','...table_name','table_name','[table_name]','dbo.table_name','dbo.[table_name]','[dbo].[table_name]' etc.,
- Validation is included at the start, when user gives other than 'table name', stored procedure would throw 'Table not exists in this Database' as error message.
- System table named SYS.OBJECTS and SYS.COLUMNS and System View named INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS are used inside the stored procedure.
- ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is used, to return the result set with the same column order that the table structure already has.
- COLLATION_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is used, to support conditions like blank is either need to consider or not, as not filled entries.
- COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is used, to show the final result set with respective fill rates.
- Dynamic Query is used, to support dynamic approach and this would avoid all the challenges that would come in static solutions like schema changes.
- Both Method 1(Dynamic Query with WHILE LOOP) and Method 2(Dynamic Query with UNION ALL) produces same result sets and carries same functionality where some metrics like CPU time, Elapsed Time, Logical reads that are better in Method 2.

***Method 1 - With the use of WHILE Loop***

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_FillRate]  
(
    @p_TableName                  NVARCHAR(128),
    @p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled   BIT = 0 -- 0-OFF(Default); 1-ON(Blank As Not Filled Data)
)
AS
BEGIN
  
BEGIN TRY
   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; 
  
--Parameter Sniffing
DECLARE @TableName                  NVARCHAR(128),
        @Include_BlankAsNotFilled   BIT,
        @ColumnName                 NVARCHAR(128),
        @R_NO                       INT,
        @DataType_Field             BIT,
        @i                          INT, --Iteration
        @RESULT                     NVARCHAR(MAX);
  
SELECT  @TableName                  =   @p_TableName,
        @Include_BlankAsNotFilled   =   @p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled,
        @i                          =   1;
          
--To Support some of the table formats that user typing.
SELECT @TableName   =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@TableName,'[',''),']',''),'dbo.',''),'...',''),'..',''),'.','');       
   
--validation
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE [TYPE]='U' AND [NAME]=@TableName )   
    BEGIN
        SELECT Result = 1 , Reason ='Table not exists in this Database' ;
        RETURN 1;
    END;
   
--dropping temp table if exists - for debugging purpose
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp;
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#Columns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Columns;
  
--temp table creations
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
[R_NO] INT NOT NULL,
[ColumnName] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
[FillRate] DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ColumnName)
);
  
CREATE TABLE #Columns
(
[R_NO] INT NOT NULL,
[Name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
[DataType_Field] BIT NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Name])
);
   
INSERT INTO #Columns ([R_NO],[Name],[DataType_Field])
SELECT
    COLUMN_ID,
    [Name],
    IIF(collation_name IS NULL,0,1)
FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TableName);
   
WHILE @i <= ( SELECT MAX(R_NO) FROM #Columns) --Checking of Iteration till total number of columns
    BEGIN
        SELECT @DataType_Field=DataType_Field,@ColumnName=[Name],@R_NO=[R_NO] FROM #Columns WHERE R_NO = @i;
   
          SET @RESULT =
            'INSERT INTO #Temp ([R_NO],[ColumnName], [FillRate]) ' +
            'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@R_NO,CHAR(39)) + ',
                ''' + @ColumnName + ''',
                CAST((100*(SUM(
                    CASE WHEN ' +
                        CASE
                            WHEN @Include_BlankAsNotFilled = 0
                              THEN '[' + @ColumnName + '] IS NOT NULL'
                            WHEN @DataType_Field = 0
                              THEN '[' + @ColumnName + '] IS NOT NULL'
                            ELSE 'ISNULL([' + @ColumnName + '],'''')<>'''' ' END +
                    ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*1.0 / COUNT(*)))
                AS DECIMAL(5,2))
            FROM ' + @TableName;
   
        --PRINT(@RESULT); --for debug purpose
        EXEC(@RESULT);
   
        SET @i += 1; -- Incrementing Iteration Count
    END;
   
 --Final Result Set
    SELECT
      ColumnName AS [Column Name],
      FillRate AS [Fill Rate (%)]
    FROM #TEMP
    ORDER BY [R_NO];
   
    RETURN 0;
  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  --error handling even it is fetching stored procedure
    SELECT
         ERROR_NUMBER()     AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY()   AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE()      AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE()  AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE()       AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE()    AS ErrorMessage;
    RETURN 1;
END CATCH;
  
END;
```

***Execute this stored procedure - Method 1 by passing the table name like below***

Execute like below if we need to consider NULL values alone as not filled

```
EXEC [Get_FillRate] @p_TableName='#TestEmp',@p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled=0;
```

Execute like below if we need to consider both NULL values and empty/blank values as not filled

```
EXEC [Get_FillRate] @p_TableName='#TestEmp',@p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled=1;
```

***Method 1 -Output***

[image]

***Method 2 - With the use of UNION ALL***

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_FillRate]  
(
    @p_TableName                  NVARCHAR(128),
    @p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled   BIT = 0 -- 0-OFF(Default); 1-ON(Blank As Not Filled Data)
)
AS
BEGIN
  
BEGIN TRY
   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; 
  
--Parameter Sniffing
DECLARE @TableName                  NVARCHAR(128),
        @Include_BlankAsNotFilled   BIT,
        @RESULT                     NVARCHAR(MAX);
  
SELECT  @TableName                  =   @p_TableName,
        @Include_BlankAsNotFilled   =   @p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled,
        @RESULT                     =   '';
          
--To Support some of the table formats that user typing.
SELECT @TableName   =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@TableName,'[',''),']',''),'dbo.',''),'...',''),'..',''),'.','');               
   
--validation
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE [TYPE]='U' AND [NAME]=@TableName )   
    BEGIN
        SELECT Result = 1 , Reason ='Table not exists in this Database' ;
        RETURN 1;
    END;
  
--dropping temp table if exists - for debugging purpose
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#Columns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Columns;
      
--temp table creations
CREATE TABLE #Columns
(
[ORDINAL_POSITION] INT NOT NULL,
[COLUMN_NAME] [sysname] NOT NULL,
[DataType_Field] BIT NOT NULL,
[TABLE_NAME] [sysname] NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ORDINAL_POSITION],[COLUMN_NAME])
);
  
INSERT INTO #Columns ([ORDINAL_POSITION],[COLUMN_NAME],[DataType_Field],[TABLE_NAME])
SELECT
    [ORDINAL_POSITION],
    [COLUMN_NAME],
    CASE WHEN COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    [TABLE_NAME]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =@tablename; --Using System_View
   
--Final Result Set
SELECT @RESULT = @RESULT+ N'SELECT '''+C.COLUMN_NAME+''' AS [Column Name],
                            CAST((100*(SUM(
                                    CASE WHEN ' +
                                        CASE
                                            WHEN @include_blankasnotfilled = 0
                                              THEN '[' + C.COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NOT NULL'
                                            WHEN C.[DataType_Field]=0
                                              THEN '[' + C.COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NOT NULL'
                                            ELSE 'ISNULL([' + C.COLUMN_NAME + '],'''')<>'''' ' END +
                                    ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*1.0 / COUNT(*)))
                            AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS [Fill Rate (%)]
                        FROM '+C.TABLE_NAME+' UNION ALL '
FROM #Columns C;
  
SET @RESULT=LEFT(@RESULT,LEN(@RESULT)-10); --To Omit 'Last UNION ALL '.
  
--PRINT(@RESULT); --for debug purpose
EXEC(@RESULT);
   
    RETURN 0;
  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  --error handling even it is fetching stored procedure
    SELECT
         ERROR_NUMBER()     AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY()   AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE()      AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE()  AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE()       AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE()    AS ErrorMessage;
    RETURN 1;
END CATCH;
  
END;
```

***Execute this stored procedure - Method 2 by passing the table name like below***

Execute like below if we need to consider NULL values alone as not filled

```
EXEC [Get_FillRate] @p_TableName='#TestEmp',@p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled=0;
```

Execute like below if we need to consider both NULL values and empty/blank values as not filled

```
EXEC [Get_FillRate] @p_TableName='#TestEmp',@p_Include_BlankAsNotFilled=1;
```

***Method 2 -Output***

[image]

***Metrics Difference between Method 1 Vs Method 2***

The below four metrics taken for consideration for knowing the difference between Method 1 Vs Method 2

- No. of Query Sets in Exec Query Plan
- Total CPU Time (in ms)
- Total Elapsed Time (in ms)
- Total Logical Reads

[image]

In conclusion, we have seen how to find the Fill Rate of a Table Using T-SQL Queries that is applicable to run in both AZURE and On-Premises SQL Databases. Thus, it would helps us to take business decisions effectively as well as immediately.